# pfSense or Proxmox with a rare networking issue

Tags: networking, ping, network-adapter, pfsense

I have a **Proxmox 5.1-35** server running on **HP Proliant ML350 Gen9**. After just installed Proxmox using a USB stick I created a **pfSense** Virtual Machine (VM) and defined three network interfaces (**vmbr0**, **vmbr1** and **vmbr2**). Each network interfaces on pfSense are named as follows **LAN**, **WAN** and **SERVERS**.

Relation between network interfaces and subnet names:

- **vmbr0** for **SERVERS**
- **vmbr1** for **WAN**
- **vmbr2** for **LAN**

Network diagram:
[image]

With pfSense just installed I was **able to access internet** from LAN subnet (**192.168.1.0/24**). But ping from LAN subnet to SERVER subnet (**172.16.10.0/24**) has replies from one server (**Proxy**) but not from another (**FreeNAS**). However, firewall (172.16.10.254) can ping any server which is rare because how firewall can ping the FreeNAS (**172.16.10.10**) and it is not able to forward ICMP packets coming from LAN to FreeNAS. As I said before, he does allow LAN to reach Proxy (**172.16.10.2**) using ICMP wich is in SERVER subnet with FreeNAS. Also, LAN can ping **Proxmox** (**172.16.10.101**)

I'd like to clarify there is no switch involved between LAN and SERVER. All comunication (except WAN) is on the HP Proliant ML350 Gen9 server itself (picture below)

[image: Physical server]

For more info I am posting the steps from the beginning:

1- Proxmox after install with no VM or Container (CT)

[image: Proxmox]

2- Creating the pfSense VM

[image]

3- pfSense was installed without any issue. Check the red boxes (version check and NTP request worked). So pfSense is reaching internet on WAN

[image: pfSense dashboard]

4- I never modified any rules on any subnet in pfSense **Rules** tab. **Almost everything** is on default values

**WAN Rules**
[image: WAN]

**SERVERS Rules**
[image: SERVERS]

**LAN Rules**
[image: LAN]

5- Creating the Proxy server CT

[image: Proxy CT creation]

6- **FreeNAS is a physical server** connected to the HP Proliant server through the gray UTP Cat5e wire.

So far I've created a VM (pfSense) and a CT (Proxy). Now I'm going to show the **ping tests**. Again, there is no problem for accessing internet from LAN. **SERVERS can not ping anything outside the subnet but I guess it's because SERVERS Rules tab is blank**. pfSense is denying packets by default from SERVERS.

**PING from LAN**

PC -> 172.16.10.2
[image]

PC -> 172.16.10.10 (**WHY???**)
[image]

PC -> 172.16.10.101
[image]

PC -> 172.16.10.254
[image]

**PING from firewall (172.16.10.254)**

firewall (172.16.10.254) -> 172.16.10.2
[image]

firewall (172.16.10.254) -> 172.16.10.10
[image]

firewall (172.16.10.254) -> 172.16.10.101
[image]

*Firewall can reach the entire SERVERS subnet even FreeNAS using ping so why is not forwarding LAN -> FreeNAS?*

**PING from Proxy (172.16.10.2)**

Proxy (172.16.10.2) -> 172.16.10.10
[image]

Proxy (172.16.10.2) -> 172.16.10.101
[image]

Proxy (172.16.10.2) -> 172.16.10.254
[image]

**PING from FreeNAS (172.16.10.10)**

FreeNAS (172.16.10.10) -> 172.16.10.2
[image]

FreeNAS (172.16.10.10) -> 172.16.10.101
[image]

FreeNAS (172.16.10.10) -> 172.16.10.254
[image]

Not posting PING test on 172.16.10.101 because there is a lot of pictures on this post.

Finally, this the **packet capture feature on pfSense** from **Source 192.168.1.111** to **Destination 172.16.10.10**

[image]

pfSense is getting the request but is not having a reply back from FreeNAS. This question is very serious for me because pfSense (as a firewall) is the very foundation on any network. I have to say this example is for diagnose and I created all pictures from the beginning because this problem happened my before with **Windows Server 2012 R2** just like FreeNAS. I put Windows Server 2012 R2 aside because I thought it was a Virtio Adapter problem in the VM settings. Now I see there is a problem or I am not getting the network concept very well.

The network schema is very very basic, why am I having this problem? I decided to stop and ask because better to fix this now than having a worse problem later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "detail" was I did not defined a gateway for FreeNAS and Proxy (when creating the container in proxmox) does have a gateway configuration (172.16.10.254). After changing this I was able to get a reply ICMP packet coming from FreeNAS. More info can be found here: [pfSense's forum post about the problem](https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=140247.0)